# Stop rendered Select escaping HTML in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

Hope this isn't really obvious. I am creating a select element, with multiple options, each option has a mathematical symbol in it.

A simplified version:

```
<select name="comparison" class="form-control filter-field toggle-display" data-replace-id="from-value"><option value="1">=</option>  
<option value="2">&amp;gt;</option>
<option value="3">&amp;lt;</option>
<option value="4">x &amp;#8804; b &amp;#8804; y</option>
</select>
```

As you can see the escapeHtmlHelper is doing it job and escaping my html codes.
It looks like the is no setting to stop this behaviour and I will need to override the renderOptions method with one of my own, is this correct?

Below is the select creation code

```
    $filter_model = new \Application\Model\Filter();
    $value_options = $filter_model->getOptions();

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'comparison',
        'type'  => '\Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control filter-field toggle-display',
            'data-replace-id' => 'from-value',
            /*'escape' => false,*/
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => $value_options,
        ),
    ));
```

Filter getOptions:

```
public function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        self::$EQUALS => '=',
        self::$GREATER_THAN => '&gt;',
        self::$LESS_THAN => '&lt;',
        self::$BETWEEN => "x &#8804; b &#8804; y",
    );
}
```

Abor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML sample you posted shows symbols that have been double-escaped. Just make sure the symbols in `$value_options` are not already escaped and your code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Tim, So to take the last option &#8804; which equates to ≤, what should I use for it to appear? the char "≤" appears as ?, and &#8804; is escaped.

Comment: Added the getOptions method from the Filter model to the question

Comment: Define them in getOptions() as you want them to appear, so ≤. If you get a ?, then make sure you're using a character set that includes that character

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to convert char set, Yup that all works perfectly, thanks again Tim